# Why \countdef, \dimendef, and alike require custom-named register to be empty before assignment?

Tags: definition, registers

Why `\dA` can't be assigned a value before it is assigned to `\dB`?

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \newdimen\dA
  \dimendef\dB\dA % ERROR IF PRECEDED BY NEXT LINE
  \dA=2.2pt % CANNOT PRECEDE PREVIOUS LINE
  \the\dB % SOME RANDOM VALUE (NOT 2.2pt)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because `\dA` doesn't act as the registers number in this case, but as the value saved in register `\dA` in `sp`, so you're trying to create a new dimen in register 144179.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for `\dimendef` is

> `\dimendef`〈control sequence〉〈equals〉〈8-bit number〉

With e-TeX extensions the number can be 15-bit; with LuaTex it can be 16-bit. The purpose of `\dimendef` is to define a control sequence that will refer to one of the available registers, ***not*** to set the value of some dimension register.

When you say `\newdimen\dA`, TeX knows the last allocated register number, say *n*, and it will do

> `\dimendef\dA=`*n* + 1

(in pseudocode). So, if the last allocated register is `42`, `\newdimen\dA` will do `\dimendef\dA=43`. Now, `\dA` will be equivalent to `\dimen43`, but one doesn't need to know the actual number, which might change from one run to another, if the code changes with a new allocation beforehand.

If you do `\newdimen\dA`, TeX allocates a new register number and sets it to 0pt (*unless you have tampered with registers assigning to them directly by register number*). If you do

```
\dimendef\dB\dA
```

the required 〈8-bit number〉 is coerced to be the value in scaled points of the register `\da`, in this case 0. Indeed

```
\newdimen\dA
\dimendef\dB\dA
\show\dB
```

will issue

```
> \dB=\dimen0.
```

However, this is clearly a misuse of the syntax. If you want to allocate a new register with the same value as `\dA`, you ***have*** to do

```
\newdimen\dA
\dA=2.2pt
\newdimen\dB
\dB=\dA
```

because `2.2pt` is `144179` in scaled points. But even if the value in scaled points was in the allowed range, after `\dimendef\dA=\dB` the newly defined register named `\dA` would contain the value `0pt`:

```
\dA=2sp
\dimendef\dA\dB
\showthe\dA
```

would answer

```
> 0.0pt.
```

The moral of the story is: *never* use `\dimendef` directly, unless you want to define names for “local register”, but

1. this *must* be done in a group;
2. you have to make sure that the code doesn't do assignments to registers that may be the same as those you use locally;
3. you don't do *global* assignments to the “local registers”.

Failure to comply with the above rules can lead to weird results.

Comment: @Skillmon That's clear, but…

Answer (score 6):

When interpreting numbers, such as the register number in expressions where TeX searches for such register numbers, TeX converts dimensions to `sp` and uses that `sp` value (without the unit) as the meant number. So in your case you're trying to define `\dB` to register number 144179, which doesn't exist.

Little document that illustrates this, I use `\dimendef\dB\dA` when `\dA` has still the value `0sp`, and get `\dimen0` as the definition for `\dB` therefore:

```latex
\documentclass[preview,border=3.14]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\newdimen\dA
\texttt{\meaning\dA}

\dimendef\dB\dA
\texttt{\meaning\dB}

\dA=2.2pt
\number\dA
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Side note:** The LaTeX2e kernel uses this fact as an optimization when accessing the 0th registers, by using the dimen `\z@`, which is 0sp. This way it can save on tokens, since TeX's memory was quite limited back in the days.